# qa automation for csv file parsing and test

Tags: python, bash, shell, parsing, scripting

Iam looking for best approach to test multiple files (about 20 - 30 files)
each with few tests ( 1 to 5 tests on each file) by parsing and validating.

1.Can this be done using bash script and still be able to maintain the code or
I should be looking for python or other OOP languages?
2.any frameworks available for testing in bash script or python?

Comment: It is too broad! Narrow it down with a minimal input, an expected output. What you have you tried and how you failed? and how do you like it to be fixed?

Comment: what are the tests? what do you have to parse? what do you have validate?  details to these questions make a world of difference as to how you approach answering this question.